# MODULE_NOT_FOUND NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ubuntu

I'm trying to launch an instance running ubuntu, running express it gives me a module not found error even tho it doesn't give me that error in my Windows machine.

The Error

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1085
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module './src/controllers/auth/passport'
Require stack:
- /var/www/PTI/Projeto/code/server/server.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1082:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:928:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:121:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/PTI/Projeto/code/server/server.js:7:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1267:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1321:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1125:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:965:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/var/www/PTI/Projeto/code/server/server.js' ]
}
```

Main.js

```
const express = require("express");
const passport = require("passport");
const session = require("express-session");
const cors = require("cors");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
require("dotenv").config();
require("./src/controllers/auth/passport");
require("./src/controllers/auth/passportGoogleSSO");
```

It gives me error module not found ./src/controllers/auth/passport

The src folder resides in the space as main.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution seems to be that in Windows machines, express doesn't seem to care about the path and if it's upper or lowercase.

the path in the main.js has auth and not Auth which is as it should be but ubuntu cares about these types of mistakes.